# htaccess, mod_rewrite, how to check for empty get var?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Breaking my head on this one..

Need to check if a get variable named 'filter' has value or not with mod_rewrite..

- `http://site.com/audio/speakers?filter=` should redirect to: `http://site.com/audio/speakers`
- `http://site.com/audio/speakers?filter=yes` shouldn't redirect..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^filter=$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^audio/speakers$ http://site.com/audio/speakers? [R=302,L]
```

It will only check for this URL: `/audio/speakers?filter=` (where `filter` is first and only one parameter and is empty) -- exactly like in your URL example. If there will be more than one parameter .. it will not match and will not do anything (even if `filter` will be empty).

You can change redirect code form 302 (temp) to 301 (permanent) if required.

**UPDATE:**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^filter=$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.com/$1? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but this only works for ^audio/speakers indeed.. While that can vary depending on the page.. Any suggestions to make this work on every url that contains an empty /filter= on the end of the url?
Thanks again!